# What is the basic file structure for Drupal 7 and where do the sites files go?

Tags: drupal-7, structure, migrate

I need to move a Drupal site. I was provided three zip files:

- code.tar.gz
- db.tar.gz
- files.tar.gz (this is images and a few CSS files)

Does the content of the "files" go inside the code structure somehow (maybe in /sites)? Or does the contents of the code and files get dumped in the root folder? I don't know why they gave me separate files.

I am not experienced with Drupal and tried putting it all into the root, but it's throwing an error and I thought I'd better check the structure first. The site isn't live yet. Just trying to connect it all.

PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in lock_may_be_available() (line 167 of /home/xxx/public_html/includes/lock.inc).

Comment: For the code it depends (what is in the archive), the best practice is to separate drupal core from contributed/custom modules, libraries & themes, so you should start with a fresh [drupal-7x](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/-/tree/7.x) install, extract the custom code into `/sites`. By default, the `files` directory goes under `/sites/default/` along with the `settings.php`. Also in `settings.php`, you should find the database settings you need to use for the db creation and access, then you can restore the dump. See [https://www.drupal.org/node/2621480](Basic Directory Structure).

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could give a look to [Drupal directory Structure's guide](https://www.drupal.org/node/2621480) on their website.

It should provide you all the knowledge to warmup your project